# Eigenvalues of real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Suppose $A$ is a  $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix with entries $a_{ij}\geq 1 $ and $a_{ii} = 0 $.
 Is it possible to have sum of the absolute eigenvalues of 
$A < 2 (n - 1).$

Comment: Do you mean "absolute value of eigenvalues"? If so, then just take any matrix for which this sum is positive, and multiply it a large constant.

Comment: After the edit, the problem becomes less trivial. However, it is still easy. Hint: consider the traces of $A$ and $A^2$. Voting to close as not research-level.

Comment: All the diagonal entries are zero.

Comment: @BorisBukh  not sure how to use the fact that $A^2$ has trace 
$\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2 \geq n^2-n$; that together with $\sum_i \lambda_i=0$
is not sufficient to prove $\sum_i |\lambda_i| \geq 2(n-1)$.
The sum-of-squares formula is not necessary either: see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this isn't a contest/homework problem…

Let $v=(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$.
Then $(v,Av) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \geq n^2-n = (n-1) (v,v)$.
Hence the maximal eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ is at least $n-1$ (Rayleigh quotient).
Since $A$ has trace zero, it follows that
$\sum_{i>1} \lambda_i = -\lambda_1 \leq -(n-1)$, so
$\sum_{i>1} |\lambda_i| \geq n-1$.
Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i| \geq 2(n-1)$,
with equality *iff* $a_{ij} = 1$ for all distinct $i,j$.  **QED**

Comment: I need to prove for <  2(n-1)

Comment: Noam, it is certainly homework or contest. The question first appeared on MSE Meta, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21366/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-matrix and with reversed inequality as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428120/eigenvalues-of-real-symmetric-matrix

Comment: LSB - the argument I gave (which I see was also given already on stackexchange) proves that the answer to "Is it possible...?" is "No."

Comment: Will - thanks for the Stackexchange link.  The Meta link doesn't work.

Comment: Noam, the Meta question was deleted by a moderator after I commented above. The link still works for me, it just shows up in pink as having been deleted. Anyway, same question, variations in wording.